# My terminal can't find my native build to upload my page

Tags: reactjs, build, gatsby, native, platform

I have an issue starting my `gatsby` website. It's regarding my native build and I can't seem to understand what its requiring me to load my page properly.

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-filesystem" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 runtime=node abi=115 uv=1 armv=8
libc=glibc node=20.0.0
    loaded from: /Users/andrew/Desktop/Skeletons/arias/a-arias-cli/node_modules/lmdb-store

  Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 runtime=node abi=115 uv=1 armv=8
   libc=glibc node=20.0.0
loaded from: /Users/andrew/Desktop/Skeletons/arias/a-arias-cli/node_modules/lmdb-store
```

I tried to update my node to accurately match whats updated with my computer, but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated!